# Calculate total weighted score based on two dataframes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, binary-tree

I have a two tables in an excel file from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3j0wo9y4p6y1ft4exsbsc/test.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=x7t0b7f1zjsl4k6d22x1plpq6), in which you can see two sheets:

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

Now I need to calculate the `total score` based on `Input` values from **Input** sheet, the calculation logic is as follows: if the input value is `1`, then calculate by `Level score * Weight` for this item, if it's `0`, then ignore those items. Finaly, we need to sum up weighted scores to get the total score.

How could we do that in Pandas or other Python packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read excel with:

```
input_df = pd.read_excel('../../../../Downloads/test.xlsx', sheet_name='input').fillna(method='ffill')

valuate_df = pd.read_excel('../../../../Downloads/test.xlsx', sheet_name='valuate').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Then you should join them to one table. If you are sure that they have the same order, use this:

```
df = input_df.join(valuate_df[['Weight', 'Level score']])
```

It chooses two columns ['Weight', 'Level score'] from valuate table and concatenate them to first table. You will have new table like this:

```
    Evaluation type Evaluation module   Evaluation index    Unnamed: 3  Evaluation content  Division level  Input   Weight  Level score
0   Business application security   User Management Ordinary account authentication NaN Evaluation item 1   Level 3 0   0.010490    3
1   Business application security   User Management Ordinary account authentication NaN Evaluation item 2   Level 3 1   0.010490    3
2   Business application security   User Management Ordinary account authentication NaN Evaluation item 3   Level 3 1   0.010490    3
3   Business application security   User Management Public account identity verification    NaN Evaluation item 1   Second level    0   0.006993    2
4   Business platform security  Business platform deployment    Platform equipment information record   NaN Evaluation item 1   Second level    1   0.006993    2
5   Business platform security  Business platform deployment    Facility distribution at home and abroad    NaN Evaluation item 1   Level 3 1   0.010490    3
6   Business platform security  Resource Scheduling Real-time resource monitoring   NaN Evaluation item 1   Second level    0   0.006993    2
7   Business platform security  Resource Scheduling Detection and processing of illegal information NaN Evaluation item 1   Second level    0   0.006993    2
8   Business platform security  Resource Scheduling System log retention    NaN Evaluation item 1   Level 3 0   0.010490    3
```

Now you can select rows where Input isn't 0:

```
df = df[df.Input!=0]
```

And then calculate total score:

```
total_score = sum(df['Level score'] * df['Weight'])
```

So total score for this example is `0.1083915`, is it?

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, You can extract the fields

Sheet1 (DataFrame 1) -> Level Score & Weight
Sheet2 (DataFrame 2) -> Input Value

and merge the both data frame in one and now you can perform your operation with new data frame.

let me know if you need code as well for the same.